# Pass an array into an SQL query using format in pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, format

I would like to do the following query by passing the value of `concepts` as a parameter value to the UDF `has_any_concept`.

The following is in the environment

```
concepts
```

```
['CREATININE_QUANTITATIVE_24_HOUR_DIALYSIS_FLUID_OBSTYPE',
 'CREATININE_QUANTITATIVE_24_HOUR_URINE_OBSTYPE',
 'CREATININE_QUANTITATIVE_SERUM_OBSTYPE']
```

This is the query without passing the parameters.

```
(spark.sql("""
select 
   
   resultCode.standard.primaryDisplay                                           as display
   
   from results 
   WHERE has_any_concept(resultCode, array("CREATININE_QUANTITATIVE_24_HOUR_DIALYSIS_FLUID_OBSTYPE","CREATININE_QUANTITATIVE_24_HOUR_URINE_OBSTYPE","CREATININE_QUANTITATIVE_SERUM_OBSTYPE"))
   
   LIMIT 3
""".format(concepts = concepts))\
   .toPandas()
)
```

```
display
0   Creatinine [Mass/volume] in Serum or Plasma
1   Creatinine [Mass/volume] in Serum or Plasma
2   Creatinine [Mass/volume] in Serum or Plasma
```

This also works

```
(spark.sql("""
select 
   
   resultCode.standard.primaryDisplay                                           as display,
   ontologicalCategoryAliases                                                   as category
   
   from results 
   WHERE has_any_concept(resultCode, array("{concepts[0]}","{concepts[1]}","{concepts[2]}"))
   
   LIMIT 3
""".format(concepts = concepts))\
   .toPandas()
)
```

```
display     category
0   Creatinine [Mass/volume] in Serum or Plasma     [LABS_OBSTYPE]
1   Creatinine [Mass/volume] in Serum or Plasma     [LABS_OBSTYPE]
2   Creatinine [Mass/volume] in Serum or Plasma     [LABS_OBSTYPE]
```

This does not work

```
(spark.sql("""
select 
   
   resultCode.standard.primaryDisplay                                           as display,
   ontologicalCategoryAliases                                                   as category
   
   from results 
   WHERE has_any_concept(resultCode, array({concepts}))
   
   LIMIT 3
""".format(concepts = [''' "{concept}"   '''.format(concept = concept) for concept in concepts]))\
   .toPandas()
)
```

```
ParseException: '\nmismatched input \'from\' expecting <EOF>(line 7, pos 3)\n\n== SQL ==\n\nselect \n   \n   resultCode.standard.primaryDisplay                                           as display,\n   ontologicalCategoryAliases                                                   as category\n   \n   from results \n---^^^\n   WHERE has_any_concept(resultCode, array([\' "CREATININE_QUANTITATIVE_24_HOUR_DIALYSIS_FLUID_OBSTYPE"   \', \' "CREATININE_QUANTITATIVE_24_HOUR_URINE_OBSTYPE"   \', \' "CREATININE_QUANTITATIVE_SERUM_OBSTYPE"   \']))\n   AND normalizedValue.typedValue.type = "NUMERIC" \n   AND interpretation.standard.primaryDisplay NOT IN (\'Not applicable\', \'Normal\')\n   \n   LIMIT 10\n'
```

I did not write the UDF `has_any_concepts`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using python 3.6+, the code can look a little cleaner if you use [f-strings](https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/inputoutput.html#formatted-string-literals).

You can't directly pass a list to the array function within the SQL syntax.

```py
spark.sql(
    f"""
    select 
       resultCode.standard.primaryDisplay as display,
       ontologicalCategoryAliases as category
    from results 
    WHERE has_any_concept(resultCode, array({", ".join([f"'{x}'" for x in concepts])}))
    LIMIT 3
    """
).toPandas()
```